# XSSF Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I used the below for setting default column style in XSSF sheet? but this is not working  can anyone suggest the bug fix.

```
format = workbook.createDataFormat();
style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(1, style);
```

Answer (score 3):

As of POI 4.1.0 it is working with SXSSF, but with a caveat.
The default column style only defines which style will be applied when users enter data into empty cells in the sheet created by POI.
If you create cells and enter data through POI, the default format does not apply, you have to use 
`setCellStyle(CellStyle)`.

E.g. for text styles:

```
private CellStyle createTextFormat(SXSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    DataFormat fmt = workbook.createDataFormat();
    CellStyle textStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    textStyle.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("@"));
    return textStyle;
}

// then do both:
int columnIndex = 0;
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(columnIndex, textFormat)

SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellStyle(textFormat);
cell.setCellValue("0100");
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably [this bug](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/DO-NOT-REPLY-Bug-51037-New-setDefaultColumnStyle-in-XSSFSheet-not-working-td4288047.html) is causing you headaches. Trying your code with Apache POI 3.7 I get the added effect that the second column gets hidden (width = 0) and the format is not applied.

Cheers,
Wim

PS Note that I talk about the *second* column, which is what your code is really referring to; if you wanted to apply the style to the first column you should have used 0 (zero-based).

Comment: I have poi-3.9-20121203.jar using SXSSFWorkbook streaming instance. Using sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle function still not working. All columns stay hidden in Excel and no style were applied. Workaround is cell.setCellStyle() function. It guess it duplicates(?) style data in .xlsx xml for each cell reference making files larger than should be. Not sure thought. It does not help using HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat() getter. Default columnstyle setter probably works for older non-streaming HSSFworkbook object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work:

```
       style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("@"));
```